# Insert html into div tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Could I have div tags in my html code like:

```
<html>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="insertHtml.js"></script>
      <div id="insertHTML">
           //html gets insterted here
      </div>
</html>
```

And when the page loads a function in the `insertHtml.js` adds html to the page?

In `insertHtml.js`:

```
function addHtml(){
  <center> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
          <td width="480" height="26" background="top.png" 
              onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');" 
              valign="center" style="cursor: pointer;border:none">
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <img src= "b1.png" name="b1" id="b1" width="120" height="120" 
         onclick="clicked(1)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/>

    <img src= "b2.png" name="b2" id="b2" width="120" height="120" 
         onclick="clicked(2)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/>

    <img src= "b3.png" name="b3" id="b3" width="120" height="120" 
         onclick="clicked(3)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/>

    <img src= "b4.png" name="b4" id="b4" width="120" height="120" 
         onclick="clicked(4)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <td width="480" height="45" background="bottom.png" 
             style="border:none" valign="center">
           <center>
               <font face="courier" size="3" color="black"> 
                  Enter name <span id="name">Name </span> Name: &nbsp; 
               </FONT>
               <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" value=""+ name +"" size="41">
               <button type="button" onclick="copyName()">Copy</button>
           </center>
        </td>
      </tr> 
    </table>
  </center>
}
```

So basically what I want to be able to do is when the script is ran it would add html content into the div?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you'll probably want to look into [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML), and you'll need to run your code *after* the div has been added to the page. And for the love of God, don't use `<center>` or `<font>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, in two steps.

1- Attach a dom-ready event handler

```
<body onload="addHtml()">
```

2- In you JS function, select the target div and insert code in it :

```
var htmlStr = '<strong>Code</strong>';
document.getElementById('insertHTML').innerHTML = htmlStr;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am trying to make it so anyone can copy and paste the code I give them. I will not have access to the body tags? Thanks

Comment: Ok, then instead of doing `<body onload="addHtml()">` simply in your script file write

`window.onload = addHtml;` after the function declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it sorted

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible. You would be wiser to place the markup in its own `.html` file, and asynchronously read the contents of that file with an [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/xhr/XMLHttpRequest) (XHR). You then copy those contents to the `.innerHTML` property of your desired `div` element.

Given the different implementations of `XHR` in various browsers, it would be wiser to use an abstracted approach through a tool like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(function () {
    $.get("contents.html").then(function( data ) {
        $("myDiv").html( data );
    });
});
```

The outer portion `$(function(){ ... });` will execute an anonymous function once the document has loaded. Inside, we call [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to read the contents of a file (`contents.html)`. Once that process has been completed, we set the resulting `data` as the innerHTML of `#myDiv` via jQuery's [`$.fn.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

Answer (score 1):

add the body tag to your HTML file:

```
<body onload="addHTML()">...</body>
```

.js:

```
function addHtml()
 {

 document.getElementById("InsertHTML").innerHTML='<center>'+
  '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">' +
  '<tr>' +
  '<td width="480" height="26" background="top.png" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');" valign="center" style="cursor: pointer;border:none">'  +
 '</td>' +
 '</tr>' +
 '</table>' +
 '<img src= "b1.png" name="b1" id="b1" width="120" height="120" onclick="clicked(1)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/><!----><img src= "b2.png" name="b2" id="b2" width="120" height="120"  onclick="clicked(2)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/><!----><img src= "b3.png" name="b3" id="b3" width="120" height="120"  onclick="clicked(3)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/><!----><img src= "b4.png" name="b4" id="b4" width="120" height="120"  onclick="clicked(4)" style="cursor: pointer;border:none"/>' +
  '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">' +
 '<tr>' +
 '<td width="480" height="45" background="bottom.png" style="border:none" valign="center">' +
  '<center>' +
  '<font face="courier" size="3" color="black"> Enter name <span id="name">Name </span> Name: &nbsp; </FONT><input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" value=""+ name +"" size="41">' +
  '<button type="button" onclick="copyName()">Copy</button>' +
  '</center>' +
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>' +
  '</table>' +
  '</center>';
 }
```

or you could create a septate string:

```
var $str = "Hello World"
document.getElementById("InsertHTML").innerHTML = str
```

Read Multi-line strings: http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings

Comment: I am trying to make it so anyone can copy and paste the code I give them. I will not have access to the body tags? Thanks